# Python 3 Opens and Decodes UTF_16_le Encoded Text File as Japanese Rather Than English

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, cjk, utf-16le

So I have developed a file transformer script that opens and extracts data from an analytical result file. The file encoding seems to change when users share the file via email, so I have to try/except to decode in 'UTF_16_le', but in the event of a UnicodeDecodeError, I then attempt to decode the file in UTF-8.

This method had worked well at first, but after testing with a few different files, I have run into an issue where one file decodes in Japanese with UTF_16_LE. I am thinking about looking for a third party tool to check and see if the generated text is in Japanese, and if so raise a custom UnicodeDecodeError that I can catch in my try statement and then attempt to decode in utf-8.

Here is my code so far:

```
def parse_by_path(path):
    if path.endswith('.txt'):
        try:
            return parse_txt_input(path, 'utf_16_le')
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            try:
                return parse_txt_input(path, 'utf-8')
            except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                error = "\nUnicodeDecodeError: Text file is not encoded the way that the transformer expects! Contact" \
                        f" Tyler with the error below:\n\nSpecific Error Details: {e.with_traceback(e.__traceback__)}"
                raise UnicodeDecodeError(e.encoding, e.object, e.start, e.end, error)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f"Uncaught Exception Decoding your file! Please Ask Tyler to check error:\n\n {e}")
    elif path.endswith('.xlsx'):
        return pd.read_excel(path, header=None)

def parse_txt_input(importfile, encoding):
    rows = {}
    i = 0
    with open(importfile, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
        for r in f:
            if i == 0:
                try:
                    new_r = r.strip('\n').split('##')[1].split('=')[0]
                except Exception as e:
                    new_r = r
                if not new_r.isalnum():
                    raise UnicodeDecodeError(encoding, r.encode(encoding), 1, 2, "Error encoding files")
            rows[i] = r.strip('\n').split('\t')
            i = i + 1
    max = 0
    for j in rows:
        if len(rows[j]) > max:
            max = len(rows[j])

    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows, orient='index')
```

So far, I have gotten it to work in a very hacky hardcoded way. The first line of the file when decoded via utf-8 has characters in it that would disqualify it from returning true to str.isascii() or str.isalnum(). Here is the text of the first line of the file: '##BLOCKS= 13' , so in order to differentiate japanese from english without using a third party tool, I have to delete the non alphanumeric characters in that line and then run str.isalnum(), but seems more complicated than it should be, I had to try catch it because the japanese text doesn't have the same split patterns.

Is their perhaps something that I could be overlooking that could solve this issue much easier? This problem didn't seem to even occur until I made a few changes today, but I have no idea what I could have done to cause my file to parse as Japanese. The coworker that sent me the file is actually a native Japanese speaker, but whenever I open the file in notepad++ it renders completely in English... Weird...

Most of my research has found people complaining about how hard it is to get Japanese to render, but somehow my english text file keeps decoding in the language that I have never used on my PC.

Oh yea here is the Japanese string:

`'믯⎿䈣佌䭃㵓ㄠല倊慬整ऺ汐瑡॥⸱ळ楔敭潆浲瑡䔉摮潰湩ॴ汆潵敲捳湥散䘉䱁䕓刉睡䘉䱁䕓ㄉउउउऱ㔴‰ㄉㄉल㘹㌉㔶ठ慍畮污उउशउㄉ㠉㌉㔶ठഉऊ敔灭牥瑡牵⡥ꇂ⥃䄉ऱ㉁䄉ळ㑁䄉व㙁䄉ष㡁䄉हㅁरㅁऱㅁलㅂ䈉ल㍂䈉ऴ㕂䈉श㝂䈉स㥂䈉〱䈉ㄱ䈉㈱䌉ऱ㉃䌉ळ㑃䌉व㙃䌉ष㡃䌉हㅃरㅃऱㅃलㅄ䐉ल㍄䐉ऴ㕄䐉श㝄䐉स㥄䐉〱䐉ㄱ䐉㈱䔉ऱ㉅䔉ळ㑅䔉व㙅䔉ष㡅䔉हㅅरㅅऱㅅलㅆ䘉ल㍆䘉ऴ㕆䘉श㝆䘉स㥆䘉〱䘉ㄱ䘉㈱䜉ऱ㉇䜉ळ㑇䜉व㙇䜉ष㡇䜉हㅇरㅇऱㅇलㅈ䠉ल㍈䠉ऴ㕈䠉श㝈䠉स㥈䠉〱䠉ㄱ䠉㈱ഉऊ慎ॎ㠱㘴ㄳ㘰स㜱㠲㜶㌹ल㜱㐹㜸㘱ऴ㠱〱ㄵ〷स㐱〰㜶㈶स㐱ㄴ㌶㜶श㔱ㄲ㔰㈲स㘱㐰㌵〴ऴㄭ㘸㐹〰ⴉ㤱㔰㘵ळㄭ㌸㜹㈴ⴉ㠱ㄷ㔹र㘸ㄷ㠷㠶㠉㈵㈵㐶ऴ㘸〵\u3130㈷㠉ㄶ㈷㌲शㄱ㐷㐴㤵श㈱㐱㐵㘹ऴ㈱〱㤲〹स㈱㔷㤹㠵र㌭㈵〵व㠭㈹㐶ⴉ㠳㘶ऴ㌱㌵㠶㔉〳㠹㈵र㤴㐹㔶㠶㐉㈴㤰ㄶल㘴㤶㔲㈷㈉㜴㘷\u3130र㌲㌳㘷〰㈉㜴㜰㤸ऴ㌲〹㐱㘷ㄉ㜴㔵㜸ㄉ㤵㐳㠰ㄉ㜵㜲ㄴㄉ㜷㠵㘶㈉ㄵ㔹㈴र㐲㘵㠷㐱ㄉ㐹〴ㄴश㤱㐶㈲㐹〉〉㔉〷㤷〸㘉㠳㤴〶㈉㌸㘴㔳㈉㌹〸㘳㈉㈹㌹〴㌉㜲〸㈸ㄉ㜲㠰㜶ष㈱㠴㈶㘲㤉㘷㠴㐲㤉㜳㠶㌳㌉㈱㘹〰㌉㔰㌸㈱㌉㘰㤲㌴㌉㔰㠲㌷㘉㤵㔹㜲㘉㔳〰㐴㜉㠱㌱㠶㘉㐸㜵㐶㘉㜰㈳㠴㘉㔸\u3130㜴㐉ㄸ㜹㈶㘉ㄶㄳ㘰ㄉ〵㈹㘸ㄉ㤴㠹㜷ㄉ㘷㐶㠷ㄉ㌵㌰㔷㈉㌶㘵ㄸस㘲㠸〷㐴㈉㤷ㄷ㜴र㠲㈳㌱㠳㈉㘷㠴㈲㌉㘰㌹㠶ㄉ㤹㠱㈱ㄉ㐹㜹〸ⴉ㐵㤹ऱㄭ㠵㘴रर㜷㈹ऴ㌱㐱〱㠶ऴ㌱㈳ㄳ〸ऴ㐱〱㔹〴ऴ㐱㜱㈶㌶श㔱㈲㌳ष㌱㌲㌴शㄸ㜸㠷㤉㠰㔸ऴㄭ㐹㐵㈹ⴉ㤱㠲㌳ऱㄭ㔹〳㌱ⴉ㠱㠸㔷ळ㔱㤵㔳ㄱश㘱㈴ㄴㄱश㜱㠳㔴㌸श㜱ㄵㄵ㠰ऴ\u0a0d\u0a0dउㅁ䄉ल㍁䄉ऴ㕁䄉श㝁䄉स㥁䄉〱䄉ㄱ䄉㈱䈉ऱ㉂䈉ळ㑂䈉व㙂䈉ष㡂䈉हㅂरㅂऱㅂलㅃ䌉ल㍃䌉ऴ㕃䌉श㝃䌉स㥃䌉〱䌉ㄱ䌉㈱䐉ऱ㉄䐉ळ㑄䐉व㙄䐉ष㡄䐉हㅄरㅄऱㅄलㅅ䔉ल㍅䔉ऴ㕅䔉श㝅䔉स㥅䔉〱䔉ㄱ䔉㈱䘉ऱ㉆䘉ळ㑆䘉व㙆䘉ष㡆䘉हㅆरㅆऱㅆलㅇ䜉ल㍇䜉ऴ㕇䜉श㝇䜉स㥇䜉〱䜉ㄱ䜉㈱䠉ऱ㉈䠉ळ㑈䠉व㙈䠉ष㡈䠉हㅈरㅈऱㅈल\u0a0dउ㠱㘴ㄳ㘰स㜱㠲㜶㌹ल㜱㐹㜸㘱ऴ㠱〱ㄵ〷स㐱〰㜶㈶स㐱ㄴ㌶㜶श㔱ㄲ㔰㈲स㘱㐰㌵〴ऴㄭ㘸㐹〰ⴉ㤱㔰㘵ळㄭ㌸㜹㈴ⴉ㠱ㄷ㔹र㘸ㄷ㠷㠶㠉㈵㈵㐶ऴ㘸〵\u3130㈷㠉ㄶ㈷㌲शㄱ㐷㐴㤵श㈱㐱㐵㘹ऴ㈱〱㤲〹स㈱㔷㤹㠵र㌭㈵〵व㠭㈹㐶ⴉ㠳㘶ऴ㌱㌵㠶㔉〳㠹㈵र㤴㐹㔶㠶㐉㈴㤰ㄶल㘴㤶㔲㈷㈉㜴㘷\u3130र㌲㌳㘷〰㈉㜴㜰㤸ऴ㌲〹㐱㘷ㄉ㜴㔵㜸ㄉ㤵㐳㠰ㄉ㜵㜲ㄴㄉ㜷㠵㘶㈉ㄵ㔹㈴र㐲㘵㠷㐱ㄉ㐹〴ㄴश㤱㐶㈲㐹〉〉㔉〷㤷〸㘉㠳㤴〶㈉㌸㘴㔳㈉㌹〸㘳㈉㈹㌹〴㌉㜲〸㈸ㄉ㜲㠰㜶ष㈱㠴㈶㘲㤉㘷㠴㐲㤉㜳㠶㌳㌉㈱㘹〰㌉㔰㌸㈱㌉㘰㤲㌴㌉㔰㠲㌷㘉㤵㔹㜲㘉㔳〰㐴㜉㠱㌱㠶㘉㐸㜵㐶㘉㜰㈳㠴㘉㔸\u3130㜴㐉ㄸ㜹㈶㘉ㄶㄳ㘰ㄉ〵㈹㘸ㄉ㤴㠹㜷ㄉ㘷㐶㠷ㄉ㌵㌰㔷㈉㌶㘵ㄸस㘲㠸〷㐴㈉㤷ㄷ㜴र㠲㈳㌱㠳㈉㘷㠴㈲㌉㘰㌹㠶ㄉ㤹㠱㈱ㄉ㐹㜹〸ⴉ㐵㤹ऱㄭ㠵㘴रर㜷㈹ऴ㌱㐱〱㠶ऴ㌱㈳ㄳ〸ऴ㐱〱㔹〴ऴ㐱㜱㈶㌶श㔱㈲㌳ष㌱㌲㌴शㄸ㜸㠷㤉㠰㔸ऴㄭ㐹㐵㈹ⴉ㤱㠲㌳ऱㄭ㔹〳㌱ⴉ㠱㠸㔷ळ㔱㤵㔳ㄱश㘱㈴ㄴㄱश㜱㠳㔴㌸श㜱ㄵㄵ㠰ऴ\u0a0d䕾摮\u0a0d汐瑡㩥倉慬整ㄭㄉ㌮吉浩䙥牯慭ॴ湅灤楯瑮䘉畬牯獥散据॥䅆卌ॅ慒ॷ䅆卌ॅऱउउㄉ㐉〵ठऱ㈱㤉श㘳‵䴉湡慵६उ㘉उउऱस㘳‵उ\u0a0d吉浥数慲畴敲숨䎡ऩㅁ䄉ल㍁䄉ऴ㕁䄉श㝁䄉स㥁䄉〱䄉ㄱ䄉㈱䈉ऱ㉂䈉ळ㑂䈉व㙂䈉ष㡂䈉हㅂरㅂऱㅂलㅃ䌉ल㍃䌉ऴ㕃䌉श㝃䌉स㥃䌉〱䌉ㄱ䌉㈱䐉ऱ㉄䐉ळ㑄䐉व㙄䐉ष㡄䐉हㅄरㅄऱㅄलㅅ䔉ल㍅䔉ऴ㕅䔉श㝅䔉स㥅䔉〱䔉ㄱ䔉㈱䘉ऱ㉆䘉ळ㑆䘉व㙆䘉ष㡆䘉हㅆरㅆऱㅆलㅇ䜉ल㍇䜉ऴ㕇䜉श㝇䜉स㥇䜉〱䜉ㄱ䜉㈱䠉ऱ㉈䠉ळ㑈䠉व㙈䠉ष㡈䠉हㅈरㅈऱㅈल\u0a0d三乡ㄉ㐸㤶ㄱ㈴ㄉ㈷㈹〸㘰ㄉ㤷㐵㈷㠳ㄉㄸㄱ㜱㈸ㄉ〴㈱㜷㈰ㄉ㐴㈲㜳〵ㄉ㈵㘱㌵㈰ㄉ〶ㄵ㐳㠷ⴉ㠱㤰㈳शㄭ㐸㐵㤸ⴉ㜱㤷㘶सㄭㄸ㠱㘷㠉㜶㜷㐹ल㔸ㄳ㜲㠱㠉㔶〶㐲श㘸㌲㌲〱ㄉ㜱〵㘴〷ㄉㄲㄵ〵㠳ㄉㄲ㠰㤹㈸ㄉ㜲㔶㘹㐵ⴉ㤲㐲ㄳⴉ㤲㤱रㄲㄴर㤱㐵㈴㔉ㄳ㠵㤵ऴ〵〰㘶㈴㐉㈴㤶㠶श㘴㔷㘲㘴㈉㠴㘳㠰ऴ㌲㤳㘷㐷㈉㜴㜶㘹स㌲㘹㔱〵ㄉ㌵㘵ㄶㄉ㔶㐳㈸ㄉ㌶㠲㔱ㄉ㌸㤵〴㈉㈵㔵㤴ऴ㐲㈶㠷㠸ㄉ㔹〰㤴र㤱〷㌲㠶㘉〰㐷㘉〰㐷㔉㘷〸㐵㘉㐴〵㐳㈉㤸㜴㤰㈉㤹ㄸ〱㈉㠹㐹㐱㌉㌳ㄸ㘵ㄉ㜲㠶㔷ऱ㈱㐵㌶〰㤉㈸㠴㠹㤉㌴㤶㜰㌉㠱㘹㐷㌉ㄱ㌸㘸㌉㈱〳㜱㌉ㄱ㤲㜴㘉㔶㘹\u3130㘉ㄴ\u3130㠱㜉㐲㐱㈴㘉〹㠵㠳㘉㌱㌳㈲㘉ㄹ㈰ㄲ㐉㜸㠹㘳㘉㜶ㄳ〸ㄉ㘵㌹〶ㄉ㔵㤹ㄵㄉ㈸㔶㈵ㄉ㤵㐰㤴㈉㐶㘱㤸ल㘲㐹ㄷ㠱㈉〸ㄳ㐵ऴ㠲㠳㐱㈱㈉㈸㠴㘹㌉㈱㐹㈴㈉㔰㠱㘸㈉〰㠹㐵㔉㠰ळ㤭㌸㘸㘉〰㐷ㄉ㜳㤹स㌱㐱〷㔷स㌱㈳ㄹ㜸स㐱ㄱ㔵㜴स㐱㠱㈲ㄷर㔱㈸ㄴऱ㌱㌸ㄵर㜸㠸㈵㤉㠶㈹सㄭ㠸㐵㠱ⴉ㠱㠶㔲षㄭ㤸㤲㤳ⴉ㠱㠲㜶ह㔱㤵㔹㤱र㘱㌴\u3130㤱र㜱㤳㔰ㄹर㜱㈵ㄱ㔱स\u0a0d\u0a0dउㅁ䄉ल㍁䄉ऴ㕁䄉श㝁䄉स㥁䄉〱䄉ㄱ䄉㈱䈉ऱ㉂䈉ळ㑂䈉व㙂䈉ष㡂䈉हㅂरㅂऱㅂलㅃ䌉ल㍃䌉ऴ㕃䌉श㝃䌉स㥃䌉〱䌉ㄱ䌉㈱䐉ऱ㉄䐉ळ㑄䐉व㙄䐉ष㡄䐉हㅄरㅄऱㅄलㅅ䔉ल㍅䔉ऴ㕅䔉श㝅䔉स㥅䔉〱䔉ㄱ䔉㈱䘉ऱ㉆䘉ळ㑆䘉व㙆䘉ष㡆䘉हㅆरㅆऱㅆलㅇ䜉ल㍇䜉ऴ㕇䜉श㝇䜉स㥇䜉〱䜉ㄱ䜉㈱䠉ऱ㉈䠉ळ㑈䠉व㙈䠉ष㡈䠉हㅈरㅈऱㅈल\u0a0dउ㠱㘴ㄹ㐱ल㜱㤲㠲〰श㜱㔹㜴㌲स㠱ㄱㄱ㠷ल㐱\u3130㜲〷ल㐱㈴㌲㔷र㔱ㄲ㔶〳ल㘱㔰㌱㜴सㄭ〸㌹㘲ⴉ㠱㔴㠴हㄭ㜷㘹㠶ⴉ㠱ㄱ㜸श㘸㜷㤷㈴㠉㌵㈱ㄷस㘸㘵㈰㘴㠉㈶㈳ㄳरㄱ㔷㐰㜶र㈱㔱㔱㌰स㈱〱㤸㠹ल㈱㘷㤵㔶ऴ㈭㈹㌴ऱ㈭ㄹ〹㈉㐱〱ㄉ㔹㐴ल㌵㔱㔸㐹㔉〰㘰㐶ल㐴㘲㘹㘸㐉㜶㈵㐶श㐲㌸〶㐸㈉㌳㜹㜶ऴ㐲㘷㤷㠶㈉㤳ㄶ㔵र㔱㔳㘶ऱ㘱㌵㠴ल㘱㈳ㄸव㠱㔳㐹र㔲㔲㐵㐹㈉㘴㜲㠸स㤱〵㐰〹ㄉ㜹㈰㘳स〶㜰ऴ〶㜰ऴ㜵㠶㔰ऴ㐶㔴㌰ऴ㠲㐹〷ह㤲㠹ㄱर㤲㤸ㄴऴ㌳㠳㔱श㈱㘷㜸ㄵㄉ㔲㘴〳र㠹㐲㤸स㐹㘳〹षㄳ㤸㜶ऴㄳ㠱㠳शㄳ㌲\u3130षㄳ㈱㐹ष㘶㤵〶ऱ㐶〱ㄱस㈷ㄴ㐴ल㤶㔰㌸सㄶ㌳㈳ल㤶〱㈲ऱ㠴㤷㌸श㘶㌷㠱र㔱㤶㘳र㔱㤵㔹ऱ㠱㘲㔵ल㔱〹㐴ह㘲ㄴ㠶㈹㈉㤶㜴ㄱस㠲㌰㔱㐴㈉㌸ㄸㄴल㠲㐲㤸शㄳ㤲㐴ल〲ㄵ㠸श〲㤰㔸ऴ〵㌸ⴉ㠹㠳श〶㜰ऴ㌱㤷㠹ㄉㄳ㜴㜰㠵ㄉ㌳㤲㠱㠷ㄉㄴ㔱㐵㠷ㄉㄴ㈸㜲〱ㄉ㠵㐲ㄱㄉ㠳㔳〱㠉㠷㔸ल㘹㤸㠲ⴉ㠱㔸ㄴसㄭ㘸㈸㜵ⴉ㠱㈹㌹हㄭ㈸㘸㤷ㄉ㔵㤹ㄵ〹ㄉ㐶〳ㄱ〹ㄉ㌷〹㤵〱ㄉ㔷ㄲㄱ㠵ഉ縊湅\u0d64䜊潲灵›䑉当瑳\u0d64匊浡汰॥敗汬ॳ潃据唉楮ॴ䙒ॕ敍湡䙒ॕ瑓敤ॶ䌥ॖ䍂ृ敍湡䍂ृ䌥彖䍂ृ別ॅ吥ॅ捁楴楶祴䴉慥䅮瑣ഉ匊䑔\u3130䄉ऱ㠱〰〮〰渉⽧䱭ㄉ㐸㌶〱㠶〮〰ㄉ㠷㐷㔹〰〮〰渉愯渉愯ㄉ㜷⸸㌹ल㜱ㄲ㜮〵㐉㘮㜹ⴉ⸴㔳㤉〮ऴ㘹⸲㌳ळ㌹⸱㜱र\u0a0dठ㉁\u2009\u2009ㄉ㈷㘸㤷㈳〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㘶⸴㘵षठठठठ〹⸰〰सठ\u0a0d呓いलㅂ㤉〰〮〰渉⽧䱭㠉㜶㜱㘸⸸〰र㔸㠹㈵㘵〮〰渉愯渉愯㠉㤲㘮㠳㠉㈲㔮㐶ㄉ㈮㘱ⴉ⸸〶㤉㠮ल㐴⸶㠱ह㐴⸲㔳श\u0a0dठ㉂\u2009\u2009㠉㈵㈵㐶⸴〰रठठठㄸ⸵㤴रठठठठ㌴⸸㈵ळठ\u0a0d呓いळㅃ㐉〵〮〰渉⽧䱭㔉〳㠹㈵⸰〰रㄵ㈵㔲㐴〮〰渉愯渉愯㔉㔰㘮〷㐉〹㔮㔲㐉㌮㘶㤉〮ऱ㌱㌮ष㜲⸰㈹ष㘲⸲㔷ल\u0a0dठ㉃\u2009\u2009㐉㤹㘴㘵⸸〰रठठठ㜴⸵㠳ऱठठठठ㔲⸴㜵सठ\u0a0d呓いऴㅄ㈉㔲〮〰渉⽧䱭㈉ㄵ㔹㈴⸰〰र㐲㠸㘱㜱〮〰渉愯渉愯㈉㠳㈮㈷㈉㔳㈮㜷ㄉ㠮〰㐉㔮ष⸶㜳ㄉ㘲㤮㠲ㄉ㔲㌮〲ഉ\u200a䐉लठठ㐲㘵㠷㐱〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㈉㈳㈮㈸\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㌲㜮㌱\u2009ഉ匊䑔㔰䔉ऱㄱ⸲〵र杮洯ौ㈱〷㘸㜷〮〰ㄉ㔲㜹㔴⸱〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡㄱ⸹ㄴसㄱ⸸㘳ळ⸱㘲र⸵ㄲ㘉㐮ष㌶㈮㠷㘉⸲ㄷव\u0a0dठ㉅\u2009\u2009ㄉ㐲㘸㈲⸶〰रठठठㄱ⸷〳सठठठठ㈶ㄮ㈵\u2009ഉ匊䑔㘰䘉ऱ㘵㈮〵渉⽧䱭㘉㜰㈳㠴〮〰㘉㘴㘱㜹㔮〰渉愯渉愯㔉⸶㜶ऴ〶㌮㔳㠉㔮ㄸ㜉㈮श㔱㠮ऴ㤲㠮〶㌉⸱〸व\u0a0dठ㉆\u2009\u2009㘉㔸\u3130㜴〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㘉⸳㤹शठठठठ㌳㜮㤴\u2009ഉ匊䑔㜰䜉ऱ㠲ㄮ㔲渉⽧䱭㈉㘷㠴㈲〮〰㈉ㄹ〷㔹〮〰渉愯渉愯㈉⸵ㄶऱ㜲〮㘳㜉㐮ㄵⴉ⸳㜸ㄉ⸱㈳ㄉ⸳ㄴल㐱ㄮ㐶ഉ\u200a䜉लठठ〳㤶㘳⸸〰रठठठ㠲㐮〶\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ⸴ㄹशठ\u0a0d呓いसㅈㄉ⸴㘰ळ杮洯ौ㔱㈲㌳⸷〰र㐱㈲㠸⸶〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㐱〮㌲ㄉ⸳㤰ह⸹㜹ष㘭㠮व㘱㠮ळ⸷ㄳर⸶㈸व\u0a0dठ㉈\u2009\u2009ㄉ㈳㐳㘳〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ⸲㜱वठठठठ⸶㐳रठ\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰潃畬湭䘉牯畭慬丠浡॥潆浲汵ॡ牐捥獩潩८潎慴楴湯\u0a0dऱ慓灭敬℉慓灭敬慎敭ॳ′敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dल敗汬ॳ圡汥䥬獄㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㌊䌉湯ॣ匡浡汰䑥獥牣灩潴ॲ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dऴ湕瑩∉杮洯≌㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㔊刉商℉敗汬慖畬獥㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㘊䴉慥剮商䄉敶慲敧刨商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dष瑓敤ॶ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dस䌥ॖ渢愯ढ‱敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dह䍂ृ湉整灲⡘䑉当瑳䁤瑓湡慤摲畃癲ⱥ䙒⥕㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊर敍湡䍂ृ癁牥条⡥䍂⥃㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊऱ䌥彖䍂ृ癃䈨䍃ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㈱┉䕒⠉䴨慥䉮䍃䌭湯⥣䌯湯⥣ㄪ〰㈉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊळ吥ॅ扁⡳別⥅┫噃䉟䍃㈉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊऴ捁楴楶祴䤉瑮牥塰✨䴴录敲䁦瑓湡慤摲畃癲❥刬商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㔱䴉慥䅮瑣䄉敶慲敧䄨瑣癩瑩⥹㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣഊ䜊潲灵匠浵慭楲獥\u0a0d楍卮摴匉慭汬獥⁴瑳湡慤摲瘠污敵ऺ㐱㈲㠸⸶〵र楍⡮敍湡䙒⥕㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲\u2063潎慴楴湯ഠ䴊硡瑓।慌杲獥⁴瑳湡慤摲瘠污敵ऺ㜱㜸㤴〵⸰〰र慍⡸敍湡䙒⥕㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲\u2063潎慴楴湯ഠ縊湅\u2064\u0a0d片畯㩰㐠啍牟晥\u0a0d慓灭敬圉汥६潃据唉楮ॴ䙒ॕ敍湡䙒ॕ瑓敤ॶ䌥ॖ䍂ृ敍湡䍂ृ䌥彖䍂ृ別ॅ吥ॅ捁楴楶祴䴉慥䅮瑣ഉ刊䙅\u3130䄉ळ〱〰〮〰甉्㜱㐹㜸㘱⸴〰र㠱㈰㤶㌴⸶〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㌹⸵㜰र㌹⸹ㄲश⸰㈶ऴ㘭〮स⸶〷㤉㔳〮〷㤉㤳㈮㘱ഉ\u200a䄉ऴठठ㠱〱ㄵ〷⸸〰रठठठ㐹⸳㘳ऱठठठठ㐹⸳㘳ऱठ\u0a0d䕒うल㍂㐉㔶ㄮ㘱甉्㘸〵\u3130㈷〮〰㠉㌶㘳〲⸴〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㐴⸵㔰र㐴⸴㤱ल⸰㜲ळ㐭㔮र⸴㜷㐉㔴〮〵㐉㐴ㄮ㈹ഉ\u200a䈉ऴठठ㘸㜱㈲㘳〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㐉㌴㌮㐳\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㐉㌴㌮㐳\u2009ഉ刊䙅㌰䌉ळㄲ⸶㌳ळ䵵㐉㈴㤰ㄶ⸲〰र㔴㔴〱㈹〮〰渉愯渉愯㈉㐲㠮㜶㈉ㄳ㈮㌹㌉㤮㤲㘉㤮ल〱㠮ऴ㈲⸴㘸ष㌲⸱㤲ळ\u0a0dठ㑃\u2009\u2009㐉㘶㈹㜵⸲〰रठठठ㌲⸷ㄷसठठठठ㌲⸷ㄷसठ\u0a0d䕒うऴ㍄ㄉ〰㘮〲甉्㤱㐴㐰㘱〮〰ㄉ㔹ㄴ㔳⸵〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㜹㔮㈰㤉⸸\u3130ष⸰㐷ळ㈭㔮ह⸳㌳㤉⸷〵ल㠹〮㜱ഉ\u200a䐉ऴठठ㤱㐶㈲㐹〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㤉⸸㌵लठठठठ㠹㔮㈳\u2009ഉ刊䙅㔰䔉ळ㘴㠮〰甉्㜹㐶㈸⸴〰र㔹〷㈸⸸〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㠴㐮㈰㐉⸷㈴ऴ⸲ㄹश⸱㌳㐉㈮व㠴㐮㈰㐉⸷㈴ऴ\u0a0dठ㑅\u2009\u2009㤉㜳㠶㌳〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㐉⸶㐴षठठठठ㘴㐮㜴\u2009ഉ刊䙅㘰䘉ळㄲ㜮㜶甉्㠴㤱㘷⸲〰र㜵㘱㌴⸴〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㌲㘮㐰㈉⸸㠰ळ㈲㔮㘵㈉⸹\u3130㔉⸱㜵㈉⸳〶ऴ㠲〮㌸ഉ\u200a䘉ऴठठ㘶㌱〱⸶〰रठठठ㈳㔮㈶\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㌉⸲㘵लठ\u0a0d䕒うष㍇ㄉ⸰㈱ऴ䵵ㄉ㤹㠱㈱〮〰ㄉ㜹㜰㘹〮〰渉愯渉愯㤉㘮㠰㤉㔮㔰ㄉ㔮㐳ⴉ⸶㈱㜉㘮व⸹〶स⸹〵व\u0a0dठ㑇\u2009\u2009ㄉ㐹㜹〸〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㤉㐮㈰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㤉㐮㈰\u2009ഉ刊䙅㠰䠉ळ⸴〷ह䵵㠉㠱㜷⸸〰र㘸㠳㘱〮〰渉愯渉愯㌉㠮〹㐉ㄮ㠰㜉㐮㤹ⴉ㈱㜮श〲㈮श⸳㤸र⸴〱स\u0a0dठ㑈\u2009\u2009㤉㠰㔸⸴〰रठठठ⸴㈳शठठठठ⸴㈳शठ\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰潃畬湭䘉牯畭慬丠浡॥潆浲汵ॡ牐捥獩潩८潎慴楴湯\u0a0dऱ慓灭敬℉慓灭敬慎敭ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dल敗汬℉敗汬䑉ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dळ潃据℉慓灭敬敄捳楲瑰牯ल″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dऴ湕瑩∉䵵ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dव䙒ॕ圡汥噬污敵ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dश敍湡䙒ॕ癁牥条⡥圡汥噬污敵⥳㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㜊匉摴癥∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㠊┉噃∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㤊䈉䍃䤉瑮牥塰✨䴴录敲䁦瑓湡慤摲畃癲❥刬商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d〱䴉慥䉮䍃䄉敶慲敧䈨䍃ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dㄱ┉噃䉟䍃䌉⡶䍂⥃㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊल別ॅ⠨敍湡䍂ⵃ潃据⼩潃据⨩〱र′敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㌱┉䕔䄉獢┨䕒⬩䌥彖䍂ृ′敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㐱䄉瑣癩瑩ॹ䈨䍃ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㔱䴉慥䅮瑣⠉敍湡䍂⥃㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣഊ䜊潲灵匠浵慭楲獥\u0a0d䕾摮ഠ䜊潲灵›䍑\u0a0d慓灭敬圉汥६潃据唉楮ॴ䙒ॕ敍湡䙒ॕ瑓敤ॶ䌥ॖ䍂ृ敍湡䍂ृ䌥彖䍂ृ別ॅ吥ॅ捁楴楶祴䴉慥䅮瑣ഉ䠊䍑ऱ㕁ㄉ〴⸰〰र杮洯ौ㐱〰㜶㈶⸸〰र㐱ㄲ㔱㔶⸲〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㌱㘴〮㌷ㄉ㘳⸵㐹ल⸲㔰ष㈭㐮㌳㐉㐮〹㜉㘲㘮ㄲ㜉㜳㐮㤲ഉ\u200a䄉शठठ㐱ㄴ㌶㜶⸶〰रठठठ㌱㔸㠮ㄱ\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㜉㠴㈮㠳\u2009ഉ䠊䍑लㅈऱ㐱〰〮〰渉⽧䱭ㄉ㌷㐸㠵㘳〮〰ㄉ㐷㤴㐸〶〮〰渉愯渉愯ㄉ㜶⸴㜰ल㘱〸㐮㔱〉㔮㐳㈉⸰㌰र〲㔮㐶㤉㔰ㄮ㘸㤉㠰㘮㌴ഉ\u200a䠉㈱\u2009\u2009ㄉ㔷㔱〱㐸〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㠶⸶㔷हठठठठㄹ⸲㤰हठ\u0a0d兌ㅃ䌉व〶〮〰渉⽧䱭㈉㜴㘷\u3130⸰〰र㐲㔰㠶㔰〮〰渉愯渉愯㈉㐳㈮㤶㈉㜲㐮㜰㐉㈮㠶㈉㤷〮ㄱ㈉㌸㈮㤷ㄉ㐲㜮㤷ㄉㄲ〮㜹ഉ\u200a䌉शठठ㌲㌳㘷〰〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㈉〲㔮㔴\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㜱㐮㔱\u2009ഉ䰊䍑लㅆऱ〶〮〰渉⽧䱭㈉㤷ㄷ㜴⸰〰र㠲㐱㐶㐰〮〰渉愯渉愯㈉㐶㜮㐸㈉㘶㐮㘵〉㠮㜸㌉㐴〮㌹㌉㐴㤮ㄸㄉㄴㄮ㔶ㄉ㈴〮㌶ഉ\u200a䘉㈱\u2009\u2009㈉㌸ㄲ㌳⸸〰रठठठ㘲⸸㈱सठठठठ㐱⸲㘹ऱठ\u0a0d免ㅃ䈉व㐲⸰〰र杮洯ौㄱ㐷㐴㤵⸶〰रㄱ㐹㤴㠷⸰〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡㄱ㘲㠮\u3130ㄉ㐱⸶㈲ळ⸲㤳श㜳⸷㤵ळ㜳⸹㠹ह〶⸷㈴हㄶ⸷㠹र\u0a0dठ㙂\u2009\u2009ㄉㄲ㔴㤴㐶〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㘱⸵㐶ऴठठठठ㈶⸸㌵ऱठ\u0a0d免㉃䜉ㄱ㈉〴〮〰渉⽧䱭ㄉㄴ㤰㐵㐰〮〰ㄉㄴ㈴〹〲〮〰渉愯渉愯ㄉ㔳⸶㐰ळ㌱㤵㈮㤷〉㌮㜳㐉㘶㌮㘶㐉㘶㜮㌰㜉㈳〮㐴㜉㌳㠮㐰ഉ\u200a䜉㈱\u2009\u2009ㄉㄴ㘷㘲㘳〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㘳⸲ㄵशठठठठ㌷⸵㘵वठ\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰潃畬湭䘉牯畭慬丠浡॥潆浲汵ॡ牐捥獩潩८潎慴楴湯\u0a0dऱ慓灭敬℉慓灭敬慎敭ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dल敗汬℉敗汬䑉ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dळ潃据℉慓灭敬敄捳楲瑰牯㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㐊唉楮ॴ渢⽧䱭ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dव䙒ॕ圡汥噬污敵ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dश敍湡䙒ॕ癁牥条⡥圡汥噬污敵⥳㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㜊匉摴癥∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㠊┉噃∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㤊䈉䍃䤉瑮牥塰䤨卄獟摴區慴摮牡䍤牵敶刬商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d〱䴉慥䉮䍃䄉敶慲敧䈨䍃ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dㄱ┉噃䉟䍃䌉⡶䍂⥃㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊल別ॅ䴨慥䉮䍃䌭湯⥣䌯湯⩣〱र″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㌱┉䕔䄉獢┨䕒⬩䌥彖䍂ृ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㐱䄉瑣癩瑩ॹ湉整灲⡘㐧啍牟晥區慴摮牡䍤牵敶Ⱗ䙒⥕㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊव敍湡捁ॴ癁牥条⡥湉整灲⡘㐧啍牟晥區慴摮牡䍤牵敶Ⱗ䙒⥕ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰畓浭牡敩൳縊湅\u2064\u0a0d片畯㩰匠浡汰獥\u0a0d慓灭敬圉汥६潃据唉楮ॴ䙒ॕ敍湡䙒ॕ瑓敤ॶ䌥ॖ䍂ृ敍湡䍂ृ䌥彖䍂ृ別ॅ吥ॅ捁楴楶祴䴉慥䅮瑣ഉ匊㤰䄉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौㄭ㘸㐹〰〮〰ⴉ㠱㜸㠴⸱〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥渉愯渉愯刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥ഉ\u200a䄉〱\u2009\u2009ⴉ㤱㔰㘵⸳〰रठठठ慒杮㽥\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009刉湡敧िठ\u0a0dㅓ䄉ष⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㔱ㄲ㔰㈲⸸〰र㔱㈶㤷ㄳ⸶〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㐱㈶㠮㘸ㄉ〵⸳ㄴष⸳ㄸळ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㤷⸰㠱रㄸ⸲㐲व\u0a0dठ㡁\u2009\u2009ㄉ〶㔴㐳㐰〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㐵⸳㐹सठठठठ㌸⸴ㄳरठ\u0a0dㅓर㥂渉愯渉⽧䱭ⴉ㔳㔲㔰〮〰ⴉ㈲㠰㐸㔮〰渉愯渉愯刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि⽮ॡ⽮ॡ慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि\u0a0dठㅂरठठ㠭㈹㐶〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009刉湡敧िठठठठ慒杮㽥\u2009ഉ匊ㄱ䌉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㐱㔷㠵⸷〰र㔱㐳㤴⸷〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㌱㔮㤸ㄉ⸴㌱श⸵㠴र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⸷㠰ल⸷㘳ह\u0a0dठㅃरठठ㔱㌹〴⸸〰रठठठ㐱㘮㐸\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㜉㘮㜵\u2009ഉ匊㈱䐉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㠲㐳㌶⸵〰र㠲㘸㌳⸵〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㘲㈮㐶㈉⸶㐷स⸲㔵ष⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㌱㜮㜵ㄉ⸴\u3130ल\u0a0dठㅄरठठ㤲㠳㌰⸶〰रठठठ㜲㈮ㄳ\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ⸴㘲षठ\u0a0dㅓळ㥅渉愯渉⽧䱭㘉㤵㔹㜲〮〰㘉㜴㜴㔸㔮〰渉愯渉愯㘉⸱㌶ळ〶㐮㠵㈉㜮〵渉愯渉愯㌉⸲㤴ऴㄳ㠮〷ഉ\u200a䔉〱\u2009\u2009㘉㔳〰㐴〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㔉⸹㠲लठठठठㄳ㈮㔴\u2009ഉ匊㐱䘉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㘲㔳㠶㠱〮〰㈉㘶ㄲ㌹⸱〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㐲⸹㘳ऱ㔲⸱㤸ळ⸱㈴ल⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㌱⸲㠸ऱ㌱⸴㐲ऱ\u0a0dठㅆरठठ㘲㠸〷㐴〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㈉㐵㐮㔲\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㔳㘮〰\u2009ഉ匊㔱䜉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㌱㐱〱㠶⸴〰र㌱㌲ㄲ㐲⸴〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㈱㈶ㄮ㐲ㄉ㜲⸰㔹ल⸰㠹ल⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㠶⸰㘹ह㠶⸵㘷स\u0a0dठㅇरठठ㌱㈳ㄳ〸⸴〰रठठठ㈱㤷㜮〸\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㘉〹㔮㠶\u2009ഉ匊㘱䠉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㔱㤵㔳ㄱ⸶〰र㘱〰㠸ㄱ⸶〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㔱〰〮㤶ㄉ㐵⸰〴व⸳〷ळ⽮ॡ⽮ॡㄸ⸰㈴ऱ㌸⸲㠳ळ\u0a0dठㅈरठठ㘱㈴ㄴㄱ⸶〰रठठठ㔱〸㜮〴\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㠉㐵㌮㘴\u2009ഉ匊㜱䔉व⽮ॡ杮洯ौㄳ㤲〶⸰〰र〳㌹㔹⸶〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㤲〮㐲㈉⸸㤶र⸱㐶व⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㔱㈮㐱ㄉ⸵㌰स\u0a0dठ㙅\u2009\u2009㌉㔰㌸㈱〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㈉⸸㔳षठठठठ㐱㠮ㄶ\u2009ഉ匊㠱䘉व⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㔱㤰㠲⸶〰र㔱㐰㠵⸱〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㌱㤮㈰ㄉ⸳㔸स⸰㐴श⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⸷㐲श⸷㈲ळ\u0a0dठ㙆\u2009\u2009ㄉ㤴㠹㜷〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ⸳ㄸऴठठठठ⸷〲रठ\u0a0dㅓह㕇渉愯渉⽧䱭ⴉ㐵㤹⸱〰रㄭ㘰㈷⸵〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥渉愯渉愯刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥ഉ\u200a䜉शठठㄭ㠵㘴⸰〰रठठठ慒杮㽥\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009刉湡敧िठ\u0a0d㉓䈉ष⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㈱〱㤲〹⸸〰र㈱㌴㐱㐷⸴〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡㄱㄶ㔮㜲ㄉ㤱⸳㔳व⸳㜷ल⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㈶⸶㤲ऴ㐶⸳㤵र\u0a0dठ㡂\u2009\u2009ㄉ㜲㤵㔹〸〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ㈲⸵㠱ळठठठठ㘶⸰㠸षठ\u0a0d㉓र㕈渉愯渉⽧䱭ⴉ㤱㔴㤴⸲〰रㄭ㌹㤶ㄱ㔮〰渉愯渉愯刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि⽮ॡ⽮ॡ慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि\u0a0dठ㙈\u2009\u2009ⴉ㤱㠲㌳⸱〰रठठठ慒杮㽥\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009刉湡敧िठ\u0a0d㉓ऱㅁऱ⽮ॡ杮洯ौㄭ㌸㜹㈴〮〰ⴉ㠱㔵㐸⸶〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥渉愯渉愯刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥ഉ\u200a䄉㈱\u2009\u2009ⴉ㠱ㄷ㔹⸰〰रठठठ慒杮㽥\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009刉湡敧िठ\u0a0d㉓लㅂऱ⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㌭㘸㐶〮〰㐉㌸㈵〮〰渉愯渉愯刉湡敧ि⸱ㄲह⸰〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ慒杮㽥〉㘮㐲ഉ\u200a䈉㈱\u2009\u2009ㄉ㔳㘳⸸〰रठठठ⸱ㄲहठठठठ⸰㈶ऴठ\u0a0d㉓ळㅃऱ⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㔱㈷㐷⸱〰र㘱㐷〳⸳〵र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㐱㐮㈹ㄉ⸵㌴ष⸸㔶ह⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⸷㔵श⸸㔰ळ\u0a0dठㅃलठठ㜱㔷㘸⸶〰रठठठ㘱㌮㈸\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㠉㔮〵\u2009ഉ匊㐲䐉ㄱ渉愯渉⽧䱭㈉㈹㌹〴〮〰㌉〱㜳ㄱ〮〰渉愯渉愯㈉⸷㔱र㠲㜮㈸㠉〮〲渉愯渉愯ㄉ⸴㈲ऴ㔱〮㘸ഉ\u200a䐉㈱\u2009\u2009㌉㜲〸㈸〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㌉⸰ㄴऴठठठठ㔱㤮㠴\u2009ഉ匊㔲䔉ㄱ渉愯渉⽧䱭㜉㠱㌱㠶〮〰㜉\u3130㔳㘶〮〰渉愯渉愯㘉⸷㈱र㔶㔮㜳㌉㐮㔱渉愯渉愯㌉⸵ㄴर㐳㔮㤶ഉ\u200a䔉㈱\u2009\u2009㘉㐸㜵㐶〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㘉⸳㔹वठठठठ㌳㜮㜲\u2009ഉ匊ळ㝃渉愯渉⽧䱭㈉㜴㜰㤸⸴〰र㐲〳㘴㔸〮〰渉愯渉愯㈉㌳㘮㤱㈉㤲㜮ㄷ㈉㌮㠶渉愯渉愯ㄉ㐲㐮〳ㄉ㈲㌮㘶ഉ\u200a䌉सठठ㌲〹㐱㘷〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㈉㔲㤮㐲\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ〲㌮\u3130\u2009ഉ匊ऴ㝄渉愯渉⽧䱭㔉〷㤷〸〮〰㘉㐰㐶〷〮〰渉愯渉愯㔉⸳㌲व㘵㐮㌲㜉㤮ㄹ渉愯渉愯㈉⸸㌰व㤲㜮㜲ഉ\u200a䐉सठठ㌶㐸㘹⸰〰रठठठ㤵㘮ㄱ\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009㌉⸱㈴रठ\u0a0d㕓䔉ष⽮ॡ杮洯ौ〳㈶㐹⸳〰र〳㜵〹⸸〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㠲㐮〰㈉⸸㔳ळ⸰㌲व⽮ॡ⽮ॡ㐱㠮㐸ㄉ⸴㔸ह\u0a0dठ㡅\u2009\u2009㌉㔰㠲㌷〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009㈉⸸〳शठठठठ㐱㠮㔳\u2009ഉ匊श㝆渉愯渉⽧䱭ㄉ㘷㐶㠷〮〰ㄉ㐶㐸㘲㔮〰渉愯渉愯ㄉ⸶㤲व㔱ㄮ㘹ㄉ⸰㈲ल⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⸸〵ऴ⸷㈹श\u0a0dठ㡆\u2009\u2009ㄉ㌵㌰㔷〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009ㄉ⸴㤰सठठठठ⸷㐳हठ\u0a0d㝓䜉ष⽮ॡ杮洯ौ⸰〰र㠳㘹⸲〰र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ慒杮㽥〉㘮㠹〉〮〰渉愯渉愯刉湡敧ि⸰㔳श\u0a0dठ㡇\u2009\u2009㜉㤷㐲〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009〉㘮㠹\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009〉㌮㘵\u2009ഉ匊स㝈渉愯渉⽧䱭ⴉ㤱㌵\u3130⸳〰रㄭ㈹㠰㌸〮〰渉愯渉愯刉湡敧ि慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि⽮ॡ⽮ॡ慒杮㽥刉湡敧ि\u0a0dठ㡈\u2009\u2009ⴉ㠱㠸㔷⸳〰रठठठ慒杮㽥\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009刉湡敧िठ\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰潃畬湭䘉牯畭慬丠浡॥潆浲汵ॡ牐捥獩潩८潎慴楴湯\u0a0dऱ慓灭敬℉慓灭敬慎敭ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dल敗汬℉敗汬䑉ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dळ潃据∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㐊唉楮ॴ渢⽧䱭ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dव䙒ॕ圡汥噬污敵ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dश敍湡䙒ॕ癁牥条⡥圡汥噬污敵⥳㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㜊匉摴癥∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㠊┉噃∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㤊䈉䍃䤉瑮牥塰䤨卄獟摴區慴摮牡䍤牵敶刬商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d〱䴉慥䉮䍃䄉敶慲敧䈨䍃ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dㄱ┉噃䉟䍃䌉⡶䍂⥃㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊल別ॅ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㌱┉䕔∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊऴ捁楴楶祴䤉瑮牥塰✨䴴录敲䁦瑓湡慤摲畃癲❥刬商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㔱䴉慥䅮瑣䄉敶慲敧䤨瑮牥塰✨䴴录敲䁦瑓湡慤摲畃癲❥刬商⤩㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣഊ䜊潲灵匠浵慭楲獥\u0a0d䕾摮ഠ倊慬整ऺ汐瑡॥⸱ळ楔敭潆浲瑡䔉摮潰湩ॴ汆潵敲捳湥散䘉䱁䕓刉睡䘉䱁䕓ㄉउउउऱ㔴‰ㄉㄉल㘹㌉㔶ठ慍畮污उउशउㄉ㠉㌉㔶ठഉऊ敔灭牥瑡牵⡥ꇂ⥃䄉ऱ㉁䄉ळ㑁䄉व㙁䄉ष㡁䄉हㅁरㅁऱㅁलㅂ䈉ल㍂䈉ऴ㕂䈉श㝂䈉स㥂䈉〱䈉ㄱ䈉㈱䌉ऱ㉃䌉ळ㑃䌉व㙃䌉ष㡃䌉हㅃरㅃऱㅃलㅄ䐉ल㍄䐉ऴ㕄䐉श㝄䐉स㥄䐉〱䐉ㄱ䐉㈱䔉ऱ㉅䔉ळ㑅䔉व㙅䔉ष㡅䔉हㅅरㅅऱㅅलㅆ䘉ल㍆䘉ऴ㕆䘉श㝆䘉स㥆䘉〱䘉ㄱ䘉㈱䜉ऱ㉇䜉ळ㑇䜉व㙇䜉ष㡇䜉हㅇरㅇऱㅇलㅈ䠉ल㍈䠉ऴ㕈䠉श㝈䠉स㥈䠉〱䠉ㄱ䠉㈱ഉऊ慎ॎ㠱㘴ㄹ㐱ल㜱㤲㠲〰श㜱㔹㜴㌲स㠱ㄱㄱ㠷ल㐱\u3130㜲〷ल㐱㈴㌲㔷र㔱ㄲ㔶〳ल㘱㔰㌱㜴सㄭ〸㌹㘲ⴉ㠱㔴㠴हㄭ㜷㘹㠶ⴉ㠱ㄱ㜸श㘸㜷㤷㈴㠉㌵㈱ㄷस㘸㘵㈰㘴㠉㈶㈳ㄳरㄱ㔷㐰㜶र㈱㔱㔱㌰स㈱〱㤸㠹ल㈱㘷㤵㔶ऴ㈭㈹㌴ऱ㈭ㄹ〹㈉㐱〱ㄉ㔹㐴ल㌵㔱㔸㐹㔉〰㘰㐶ल㐴㘲㘹㘸㐉㜶㈵㐶श㐲㌸〶㐸㈉㌳㜹㜶ऴ㐲㘷㤷㠶㈉㤳ㄶ㔵र㔱㔳㘶ऱ㘱㌵㠴ल㘱㈳ㄸव㠱㔳㐹र㔲㔲㐵㐹㈉㘴㜲㠸स㤱〵㐰〹ㄉ㜹㈰㘳स〶㜰ऴ〶㜰ऴ㜵㠶㔰ऴ㐶㔴㌰ऴ㠲㐹〷ह㤲㠹ㄱर㤲㤸ㄴऴ㌳㠳㔱श㈱㘷㜸ㄵㄉ㔲㘴〳र㠹㐲㤸स㐹㘳〹षㄳ㤸㜶ऴㄳ㠱㠳शㄳ㌲\u3130षㄳ㈱㐹ष㘶㤵〶ऱ㐶〱ㄱस㈷ㄴ㐴ल㤶㔰㌸सㄶ㌳㈳ल㤶〱㈲ऱ㠴㤷㌸श㘶㌷㠱र㔱㤶㘳र㔱㤵㔹ऱ㠱㘲㔵ल㔱〹㐴ह㘲ㄴ㠶㈹㈉㤶㜴ㄱस㠲㌰㔱㐴㈉㌸ㄸㄴल㠲㐲㤸शㄳ㤲㐴ल〲ㄵ㠸श〲㤰㔸ऴ〵㌸ⴉ㠹㠳श〶㜰ऴ㌱㤷㠹ㄉㄳ㜴㜰㠵ㄉ㌳㤲㠱㠷ㄉㄴ㔱㐵㠷ㄉㄴ㈸㜲〱ㄉ㠵㐲ㄱㄉ㠳㔳〱㠉㠷㔸ल㘹㤸㠲ⴉ㠱㔸ㄴसㄭ㘸㈸㜵ⴉ㠱㈹㌹हㄭ㈸㘸㤷ㄉ㔵㤹ㄵ〹ㄉ㐶〳ㄱ〹ㄉ㌷〹㤵〱ㄉ㔷ㄲㄱ㠵ഉഊऊ䄉ऱ㉁䄉ळ㑁䄉व㙁䄉ष㡁䄉हㅁरㅁऱㅁलㅂ䈉ल㍂䈉ऴ㕂䈉श㝂䈉स㥂䈉〱䈉ㄱ䈉㈱䌉ऱ㉃䌉ळ㑃䌉व㙃䌉ष㡃䌉हㅃरㅃऱㅃलㅄ䐉ल㍄䐉ऴ㕄䐉श㝄䐉स㥄䐉〱䐉ㄱ䐉㈱䔉ऱ㉅䔉ळ㑅䔉व㙅䔉ष㡅䔉हㅅरㅅऱㅅलㅆ䘉ल㍆䘉ऴ㕆䘉श㝆䘉स㥆䘉〱䘉ㄱ䘉㈱䜉ऱ㉇䜉ळ㑇䜉व㙇䜉ष㡇䜉हㅇरㅇऱㅇलㅈ䠉ल㍈䠉ऴ㕈䠉श㝈䠉स㥈䠉〱䠉ㄱ䠉㈱ഉऊㄉ㐸㤶ㄱ㈴ㄉ㈷㈹〸㘰ㄉ㤷㐵㈷㠳ㄉㄸㄱ㜱㈸ㄉ〴㈱㜷㈰ㄉ㐴㈲㜳〵ㄉ㈵㘱㌵㈰ㄉ〶ㄵ㐳㠷ⴉ㠱㤰㈳शㄭ㐸㐵㤸ⴉ㜱㤷㘶सㄭㄸ㠱㘷㠉㜶㜷㐹ल㔸ㄳ㜲㠱㠉㔶〶㐲श㘸㌲㌲〱ㄉ㜱〵㘴〷ㄉㄲㄵ〵㠳ㄉㄲ㠰㤹㈸ㄉ㜲㔶㘹㐵ⴉ㤲㐲ㄳⴉ㤲㤱रㄲㄴर㤱㐵㈴㔉ㄳ㠵㤵ऴ〵〰㘶㈴㐉㈴㤶㠶श㘴㔷㘲㘴㈉㠴㘳㠰ऴ㌲㤳㘷㐷㈉㜴㜶㘹स㌲㘹㔱〵ㄉ㌵㘵ㄶㄉ㔶㐳㈸ㄉ㌶㠲㔱ㄉ㌸㤵〴㈉㈵㔵㤴ऴ㐲㈶㠷㠸ㄉ㔹〰㤴र㤱〷㌲㠶㘉〰㐷㘉〰㐷㔉㘷〸㐵㘉㐴〵㐳㈉㤸㜴㤰㈉㤹ㄸ〱㈉㠹㐹㐱㌉㌳ㄸ㘵ㄉ㜲㠶㔷ऱ㈱㐵㌶〰㤉㈸㠴㠹㤉㌴㤶㜰㌉㠱㘹㐷㌉ㄱ㌸㘸㌉㈱〳㜱㌉ㄱ㤲㜴㘉㔶㘹\u3130㘉ㄴ\u3130㠱㜉㐲㐱㈴㘉〹㠵㠳㘉㌱㌳㈲㘉ㄹ㈰ㄲ㐉㜸㠹㘳㘉㜶ㄳ〸ㄉ㘵㌹〶ㄉ㔵㤹ㄵㄉ㈸㔶㈵ㄉ㤵㐰㤴㈉㐶㘱㤸ल㘲㐹ㄷ㠱㈉〸ㄳ㐵ऴ㠲㠳㐱㈱㈉㈸㠴㘹㌉㈱㐹㈴㈉㔰㠱㘸㈉〰㠹㐵㔉㠰ळ㤭㌸㘸㘉〰㐷ㄉ㜳㤹स㌱㐱〷㔷स㌱㈳ㄹ㜸स㐱ㄱ㔵㜴स㐱㠱㈲ㄷर㔱㈸ㄴऱ㌱㌸ㄵर㜸㠸㈵㤉㠶㈹सㄭ㠸㐵㠱ⴉ㠱㠶㔲षㄭ㤸㤲㤳ⴉ㠱㠲㜶ह㔱㤵㔹㤱र㘱㌴\u3130㤱र㜱㤳㔰ㄹर㜱㈵ㄱ㔱स\u0a0d䕾摮\u0a0d汐瑡㩥倉慬整ㄭㄉ㌮吉浩䙥牯慭ॴ湅灤楯瑮䘉畬牯獥散据॥䅆卌ॅ慒ॷ䅆卌ॅऱउउㄉ㐉〵ठऱ㈱㤉श㘳‵䴉湡慵६उ㘉उउऱस㘳‵उ\u0a0d吉浥数慲畴敲숨䎡ऩㅁ䄉ल㍁䄉ऴ㕁䄉श㝁䄉स㥁䄉〱䄉ㄱ䄉㈱䈉ऱ㉂䈉ळ㑂䈉व㙂䈉ष㡂䈉हㅂरㅂऱㅂलㅃ䌉ल㍃䌉ऴ㕃䌉श㝃䌉स㥃䌉〱䌉ㄱ䌉㈱䐉ऱ㉄䐉ळ㑄䐉व㙄䐉ष㡄䐉हㅄरㅄऱㅄलㅅ䔉ल㍅䔉ऴ㕅䔉श㝅䔉स㥅䔉〱䔉ㄱ䔉㈱䘉ऱ㉆䘉ळ㑆䘉व㙆䘉ष㡆䘉हㅆरㅆऱㅆलㅇ䜉ल㍇䜉ऴ㕇䜉श㝇䜉स㥇䜉〱䜉ㄱ䜉㈱䠉ऱ㉈䠉ळ㑈䠉व㙈䠉ष㡈䠉हㅈरㅈऱㅈल\u0a0d三乡ㄉ㐸㤶ㄱ㈴ㄉ㈷㈹〸㘰ㄉ㤷㐵㈷㠳ㄉㄸㄱ㜱㈸ㄉ〴㈱㜷㈰ㄉ㐴㈲㜳〵ㄉ㈵㘱㌵㈰ㄉ〶ㄵ㐳㠷ⴉ㠱㤰㈳शㄭ㐸㐵㤸ⴉ㜱㤷㘶सㄭㄸ㠱㘷㠉㜶㜷㐹ल㔸ㄳ㜲㠱㠉㔶〶㐲श㘸㌲㌲〱ㄉ㜱〵㘴〷ㄉㄲㄵ〵㠳ㄉㄲ㠰㤹㈸ㄉ㜲㔶㘹㐵ⴉ㤲㐲ㄳⴉ㤲㤱रㄲㄴर㤱㐵㈴㔉ㄳ㠵㤵ऴ〵〰㘶㈴㐉㈴㤶㠶श㘴㔷㘲㘴㈉㠴㘳㠰ऴ㌲㤳㘷㐷㈉㜴㜶㘹स㌲㘹㔱〵ㄉ㌵㘵ㄶㄉ㔶㐳㈸ㄉ㌶㠲㔱ㄉ㌸㤵〴㈉㈵㔵㤴ऴ㐲㈶㠷㠸ㄉ㔹〰㤴र㤱〷㌲㠶㘉〰㐷㘉〰㐷㔉㘷〸㐵㘉㐴〵㐳㈉㤸㜴㤰㈉㤹ㄸ〱㈉㠹㐹㐱㌉㌳ㄸ㘵ㄉ㜲㠶㔷ऱ㈱㐵㌶〰㤉㈸㠴㠹㤉㌴㤶㜰㌉㠱㘹㐷㌉ㄱ㌸㘸㌉㈱〳㜱㌉ㄱ㤲㜴㘉㔶㘹\u3130㘉ㄴ\u3130㠱㜉㐲㐱㈴㘉〹㠵㠳㘉㌱㌳㈲㘉ㄹ㈰ㄲ㐉㜸㠹㘳㘉㜶ㄳ〸ㄉ㘵㌹〶ㄉ㔵㤹ㄵㄉ㈸㔶㈵ㄉ㤵㐰㤴㈉㐶㘱㤸ल㘲㐹ㄷ㠱㈉〸ㄳ㐵ऴ㠲㠳㐱㈱㈉㈸㠴㘹㌉㈱㐹㈴㈉㔰㠱㘸㈉〰㠹㐵㔉㠰ळ㤭㌸㘸㘉〰㐷ㄉ㜳㤹स㌱㐱〷㔷स㌱㈳ㄹ㜸स㐱ㄱ㔵㜴स㐱㠱㈲ㄷर㔱㈸ㄴऱ㌱㌸ㄵर㜸㠸㈵㤉㠶㈹सㄭ㠸㐵㠱ⴉ㠱㠶㔲षㄭ㤸㤲㤳ⴉ㠱㠲㜶ह㔱㤵㔹㤱र㘱㌴\u3130㤱र㜱㤳㔰ㄹर㜱㈵ㄱ㔱स\u0a0d\u0a0dउㅁ䄉ल㍁䄉ऴ㕁䄉श㝁䄉स㥁䄉〱䄉ㄱ䄉㈱䈉ऱ㉂䈉ळ㑂䈉व㙂䈉ष㡂䈉हㅂरㅂऱㅂलㅃ䌉ल㍃䌉ऴ㕃䌉श㝃䌉स㥃䌉〱䌉ㄱ䌉㈱䐉ऱ㉄䐉ळ㑄䐉व㙄䐉ष㡄䐉हㅄरㅄऱㅄलㅅ䔉ल㍅䔉ऴ㕅䔉श㝅䔉स㥅䔉〱䔉ㄱ䔉㈱䘉ऱ㉆䘉ळ㑆䘉व㙆䘉ष㡆䘉हㅆरㅆऱㅆलㅇ䜉ल㍇䜉ऴ㕇䜉श㝇䜉स㥇䜉〱䜉ㄱ䜉㈱䠉ऱ㉈䠉ळ㑈䠉व㙈䠉ष㡈䠉हㅈरㅈऱㅈल\u0a0dउ㠱㘴ㄹ㐱ल㜱㤲㠲〰श㜱㔹㜴㌲स㠱ㄱㄱ㠷ल㐱\u3130㜲〷ल㐱㈴㌲㔷र㔱ㄲ㔶〳ल㘱㔰㌱㜴सㄭ〸㌹㘲ⴉ㠱㔴㠴हㄭ㜷㘹㠶ⴉ㠱ㄱ㜸श㘸㜷㤷㈴㠉㌵㈱ㄷस㘸㘵㈰㘴㠉㈶㈳ㄳरㄱ㔷㐰㜶र㈱㔱㔱㌰स㈱〱㤸㠹ल㈱㘷㤵㔶ऴ㈭㈹㌴ऱ㈭ㄹ〹㈉㐱〱ㄉ㔹㐴ल㌵㔱㔸㐹㔉〰㘰㐶ल㐴㘲㘹㘸㐉㜶㈵㐶श㐲㌸〶㐸㈉㌳㜹㜶ऴ㐲㘷㤷㠶㈉㤳ㄶ㔵र㔱㔳㘶ऱ㘱㌵㠴ल㘱㈳ㄸव㠱㔳㐹र㔲㔲㐵㐹㈉㘴㜲㠸स㤱〵㐰〹ㄉ㜹㈰㘳स〶㜰ऴ〶㜰ऴ㜵㠶㔰ऴ㐶㔴㌰ऴ㠲㐹〷ह㤲㠹ㄱर㤲㤸ㄴऴ㌳㠳㔱श㈱㘷㜸ㄵㄉ㔲㘴〳र㠹㐲㤸स㐹㘳〹षㄳ㤸㜶ऴㄳ㠱㠳शㄳ㌲\u3130षㄳ㈱㐹ष㘶㤵〶ऱ㐶〱ㄱस㈷ㄴ㐴ल㤶㔰㌸सㄶ㌳㈳ल㤶〱㈲ऱ㠴㤷㌸श㘶㌷㠱र㔱㤶㘳र㔱㤵㔹ऱ㠱㘲㔵ल㔱〹㐴ह㘲ㄴ㠶㈹㈉㤶㜴ㄱस㠲㌰㔱㐴㈉㌸ㄸㄴल㠲㐲㤸शㄳ㤲㐴ल〲ㄵ㠸श〲㤰㔸ऴ〵㌸ⴉ㠹㠳श〶㜰ऴ㌱㤷㠹ㄉㄳ㜴㜰㠵ㄉ㌳㤲㠱㠷ㄉㄴ㔱㐵㠷ㄉㄴ㈸㜲〱ㄉ㠵㐲ㄱㄉ㠳㔳〱㠉㠷㔸ल㘹㤸㠲ⴉ㠱㔸ㄴसㄭ㘸㈸㜵ⴉ㠱㈹㌹हㄭ㈸㘸㤷ㄉ㔵㤹ㄵ〹ㄉ㐶〳ㄱ〹ㄉ㌷〹㤵〱ㄉ㔷ㄲㄱ㠵ഉ縊湅\u0d64䜊潲灵›䑉当瑳\u0d64匊浡汰॥敗汬ॳ潃据唉楮ॴ䙒ॕ敍湡䙒ॕ瑓敤ॶ䌥ॖ䍂ृ敍湡䍂ृ䌥彖䍂ृ別ॅ吥ॅ捁楴楶祴䴉慥䅮瑣ഉ匊䑔\u3130䄉ऱ㠱〰〮〰渉⽧䱭ㄉ㐸㤶ㄱ㈴〮〰ㄉ㠷〸㔹㐷〮〰㠉ㄳ㜷㌹㈮㐳㐉㜮渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䄉लठठ㜱㤲㠲〰⸶〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d呓いलㅂ㤉〰〮〰渉⽧䱭㠉㜶㜷㐹⸲〰र㘸㐰㌵〳〮〰ㄉ㌰〶㤶㠮㘲ㄉ㈮渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䈉लठठ㔸ㄳ㜲㠱〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊䑔㌰䌉ऱ㔴⸰〰र杮洯ौ㌵㔱㔸㐹〮〰㔉㔱㈸ㄶ⸸〰र㈲㠲㘷⸶㌶ळ⸴ळ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㉃\u2009\u2009㔉〰㘰㐶⸲〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d呓いऴㅄ㈉㔲〮〰渉⽧䱭㈉㈵㔵㤴⸴〰र㐲㐹㘱ㄹ〮〰㐉㌴㠷⸴㔴ह⸱स⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㉄\u2009\u2009㈉㘴㜲㠸⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d呓いवㅅㄉ㈱㔮〰渉⽧䱭ㄉ㜲㠶㔷⸱〰र㈱㔶㔷㔲㔮〰ㄉ㜵㤲⸶ㄶऱ⸱ल⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㉅\u2009\u2009ㄉ㔲㘴〳⸰〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d呓いशㅆ㔉⸶㔲र杮洯ौㄶ㌳㈳⸲〰र㔶ㄲ㜷⸱〵र㐵㌹〵㔮ㄵ㠉㐮渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䘉लठठ㤶〱㈲⸱〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d呓いषㅇ㈉⸸㈱व杮洯ौ㠲㐲㤸⸶〰र㤲㜷㘱⸹〰रㄲ㌵㘴㔮㈴㜉㈮渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䜉लठठㄳ㤲㐴⸲〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d呓いसㅈㄉ⸴㘰ळ杮洯ौ㔱㈸ㄴ⸱〰र㐱㈸㘹⸰〵र㐱㘰㐴㈮㘴㤉㔮渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䠉लठठ㌱㌸ㄵ⸰〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰潃畬湭䘉牯畭慬丠浡॥潆浲汵ॡ牐捥獩潩८潎慴楴湯\u0a0dऱ慓灭敬℉慓灭敬慎敭ॳ′敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dल敗汬ॳ圡汥䥬獄㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㌊䌉湯ॣ匡浡汰䑥獥牣灩潴ॲ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dऴ湕瑩∉杮洯≌㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㔊刉商℉敗汬慖畬獥㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㘊䴉慥剮商䄉敶慲敧刨商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dष瑓敤ॶ瑓敤⡶䙒⥕㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㠊┉噃䌉⡶䙒⥕ㄉ搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㤊䈉䍃∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊर敍湡䍂ृ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dㄱ┉噃䉟䍃∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊल別ॅ渢愯ढ′敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㌱┉䕔∉⽮≡㈉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊऴ捁楴楶祴∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊव敍湡捁ॴ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰畓浭牡敩൳䴊湩瑓।浓污敬瑳猠慴摮牡\u2064慶畬㩥ㄉ㠴㤲〶㔮〰䴉湩䴨慥剮商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩丠瑯瑡潩\u206e\u0a0d慍卸摴䰉牡敧瑳猠慴摮牡\u2064慶畬㩥ㄉ㠷〸㔹㐷〮〰䴉硡䴨慥剮商ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩丠瑯瑡潩\u206e\u0a0d䕾摮ഠ䜊潲灵›䴴录敲൦匊浡汰॥敗汬䌉湯ॣ湕瑩刉商䴉慥剮商匉摴癥┉噃䈉䍃䴉慥䉮䍃┉噃䉟䍃┉䕒┉䕔䄉瑣癩瑩ॹ敍湡捁ॴ\u0a0d䕒うऱ㍁ㄉ〰⸰〰र䵵ㄉ㤷㐵㈷㠳〮〰ㄉ〸㈳㔹〱〮〰ㄉ〱㈶㤹㘮㈷〉㘮㌱渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䄉ऴठठ㠱ㄱㄱ㠷⸲〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d䕒うल㍂㐉㔶ㄮ㘱甉्㘸㘵㈰㘴〮〰㠉㌶㘹㜲⸸〰र㌲㠱㔸㜮㤶〉㈮㠶渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䈉ऴठठ㘸㌲㌲〱〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ刊䙅㌰䌉ळㄲ⸶㌳ळ䵵㐉㈴㤶㠶⸶〰र㔴ㄵㄱ㘶〮〰ㄉ㔷㜵㜱㠮㌵㌉㠮㠵渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䌉ऴठठ㘴㔷㘲㘴〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ刊䙅㐰䐉ळ〱⸰㈶र䵵ㄉ㔹〰㤴⸰〰र㤱〶㐱㤲〮〰ㄉ㈴㐷⸹〳ळ⸰㈷स⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㑄\u2009\u2009ㄉ㜹㈰㘳⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d䕒うव㍅㐉⸶〸र䵵㤉㈸㠴㠹〮〰㤉㌶㤰㈰㔮〰㈉㐷㔳⸱㘰ष⸲㐸ह⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㑅\u2009\u2009㤉㌴㤶㜰〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ刊䙅㘰䘉ळㄲ㜮㜶甉्㠴㤷㌸⸶〰र㜵㘷〵⸸〰र㈱㠶㠰⸵〷ळㄲ㤮㈵渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䘉ऴठठ㘶㌷㠱⸰〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d䕒うष㍇ㄉ⸰㈱ऴ䵵㈉㔰㠱㘸〮〰㈉㌰㠰〷〮〰㈉㜹ㄲㄮ㈱ㄉ㐮㌶渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䜉ऴठठ〲㤰㔸⸴〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d䕒うस㍈㐉㜮㤰甉्㜸㠸㈵〮〰㤉㌲㤸⸰〰र㌶㤶⸳㔳र⸶㤸ऴ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㑈\u2009\u2009㤉㠶㈹⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰潃畬湭䘉牯畭慬丠浡॥潆浲汵ॡ牐捥獩潩८潎慴楴湯\u0a0dऱ慓灭敬℉慓灭敬慎敭ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dल敗汬℉敗汬䑉ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dळ潃据℉慓灭敬敄捳楲瑰牯ल″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dऴ湕瑩∉䵵ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dव䙒ॕ圡汥噬污敵ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dश敍湡䙒ॕ癁牥条⡥圡汥噬污敵⥳㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㜊匉摴癥匉摴癥ℨ敗汬慖畬獥ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dस䌥ॖ癃ℨ敗汬慖畬獥ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dह䍂ृ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d〱䴉慥䉮䍃∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊऱ䌥彖䍂ृ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㈱┉䕒∉⽮≡㈉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊळ吥ॅ渢愯ढ′敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㐱䄉瑣癩瑩ॹ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㔱䴉慥䅮瑣∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣഊ䜊潲灵匠浵慭楲獥\u0a0d䕾摮ഠ䜊潲灵›䍑\u0a0d慓灭敬圉汥६潃据唉楮ॴ䙒ॕ敍湡䙒ॕ瑓敤ॶ䌥ॖ䍂ृ敍湡䍂ृ䌥彖䍂ृ別ॅ吥ॅ捁楴楶祴䴉慥䅮瑣ഉ䠊䍑ऱ㕁ㄉ〴⸰〰र杮洯ौ㐱\u3130㜲〷⸲〰र㐱ㄲ㔷㈷⸶〰र㠲㘹㐳⸳ㄳष⸲㌰ष⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㙁\u2009\u2009ㄉ㐴㈲㜳〵〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ䠊䍑लㅈऱ㐱〰〮〰渉⽧䱭ㄉ㌷〹㤵〱〮〰ㄉ㐷㔵㔸㐳〮〰㤉㈲㐹⸹ㄷल⸰㈵ह⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅈलठठ㜱㈵ㄱ㔱⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d兌ㅃ䌉व〶〮〰渉⽧䱭㈉㠴㘳㠰⸴〰र㐲ㄱ㠶㤷〮〰ㄉ\u3130ㄷ㤰㐮㔶㐉㈮㜱渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䌉शठठ㌲㤳㘷㐷〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ䰊䍑लㅆऱ〶〮〰渉⽧䱭㈉〸ㄳ㐵⸴〰र㠲〲㐶㠷〮〰㈉㜴㤳⸴㌰व⸰㜸ष⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅆलठठ㠲㠳㐱㈱〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ䴊䍑ऱ㕂㈉〴〮〰渉⽧䱭ㄉ㜱〵㘴〷〮〰ㄉ㤱〵㠹㐵〮〰㈉㌸㜵㠵㐮㠰㈉㌮㌷渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䈉शठठ㈱㔱㔱㌰⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d免㉃䜉ㄱ㈉〴〮〰渉⽧䱭ㄉㄴ㔱㐵㠷〮〰ㄉㄴ㠴〹㐹〮〰㐉ㄷ〸⸴㜲ल⸰㌳ळ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅇलठठ㐱㠱㈲ㄷ⸰〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰潃畬湭䘉牯畭慬丠浡॥潆浲汵ॡ牐捥獩潩८潎慴楴湯\u0a0dऱ慓灭敬℉慓灭敬慎敭ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dल敗汬℉敗汬䑉ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dळ潃据℉慓灭敬敄捳楲瑰牯㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㐊唉楮ॴ渢⽧䱭ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dव䙒ॕ圡汥噬污敵ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dश敍湡䙒ॕ癁牥条⡥圡汥噬污敵⥳㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㜊匉摴癥匉摴癥ℨ敗汬慖畬獥ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dस䌥ॖ癃ℨ敗汬慖畬獥ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dह䍂ृ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d〱䴉慥䉮䍃∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊऱ䌥彖䍂ृ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㈱┉䕒∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊळ吥ॅ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㐱䄉瑣癩瑩ॹ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㔱䴉慥䅮瑣∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣഊ䜊潲灵匠浵慭楲獥\u0a0d䕾摮ഠ䜊潲灵›慓灭敬൳匊浡汰॥敗汬䌉湯ॣ湕瑩刉商䴉慥剮商匉摴癥┉噃䈉䍃䴉慥䉮䍃┉噃䉟䍃┉䕒┉䕔䄉瑣癩瑩ॹ敍湡捁ॴ\u0a0dこह㥁渉愯渉⽧䱭ⴉ㠱㤰㈳⸶〰रㄭ㈸㐷㜰㔮〰㈉㔵ㄷㄮ㌰ㄉ㌮㤹渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䄉〱\u2009\u2009ⴉ㠱㔴㠴⸹〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0dㅓ䄉ष⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㔱ㄲ㔶〳⸲〰र㔱㌶㤳㤳⸰〰र㤵㌰㔰⸱㘸र⸳㜷श⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㡁\u2009\u2009ㄉ〶ㄵ㐳㠷〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊〱䈉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㈭㈹㌴⸱〰रㄭ〶ㄸ⸰〵र㠱ㄶ㤳㐮㘹ㄉ㔱㜮ㄵ渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䈉〱\u2009\u2009ⴉ㤲㤱⸰〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0dㅓऱ㥃渉愯渉⽧䱭ㄉ㌵㘵ㄶ〮〰ㄉ㤵㔴ㄷ㔮〰㠉㌳㈱〮㠲㔉㈮㔲渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䌉〱\u2009\u2009ㄉ㔶㐳㈸〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊㈱䐉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㠲㐹〷⸹〰र㤲㘴〴⸹〵र㌷ㄱ⸵㐵स⸲㠴ल⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅄरठठ㤲㠹ㄱ⸰〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0dㅓळ㥅渉愯渉⽧䱭㘉㔶㘹\u3130〮〰㘉㌵㠴㤵㔮〰ㄉ㘷ㄴ⸱㈱ऱ⸲〷र⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅅरठठ㐶〱ㄱ⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0dㅓऴ㥆渉愯渉⽧䱭㈉㐶㘱㤸⸲〰र㘲㠶〲㔰〮〰㌉㐷㈹⸶〴र⸱〴व⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅆरठठ㘲㐹ㄷ㠱〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊㔱䜉ह⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㌱㐱〷㔷⸸〰र㌱㌲ㄸㄳ⸸〰र㈱㜸㈷⸶〳ऱ⸰㜹ळ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅇरठठ㌱㈳ㄹ㜸⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0dㅓश㥈渉愯渉⽧䱭ㄉ㔵㤹ㄵ〹〮〰ㄉ〶㐱ㄸ〹〮〰㔉㜸㈳㠲㤮㔲㌉㘮㜶渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䠉〱\u2009\u2009ㄉ㐶〳ㄱ〹〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊㜱䔉व⽮ॡ杮洯ौㄳ㤸㜶⸴〰रㄳ㐵㌰⸰〰र〵〴⸸㈲स⸱㤵स⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㙅\u2009\u2009㌉ㄱ㌸㘸〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊㠱䘉व⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㔱㤶㘳⸰〰र㔱㐶㔶⸵〵र㘶㌵ㄮ㠶〉㐮㔲渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䘉शठठ㔱㤵㔹⸱〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0dㅓह㕇渉愯渉⽧䱭㔉㠰⸳〰र㐭㘶ㄵ㔮〰㜉ㄳ㌶㘮㈳ㄉ㘵㠮〳渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䜉शठठ㤭㌸㘸〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊ल㝂渉愯渉⽧䱭ㄉㄲ㠰㤹㈸〮〰ㄉ㐲㜳㠴㠱〮〰㐉㐶㐵㤵㘮ㄲ㌉㜮㔳渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䈉सठठ㈱㘷㤵㔶⸴〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d㉓र㕈渉愯渉⽧䱭ⴉ㠱㔸ㄴ⸸〰रㄭ㜸㠶㜳㔮〰ㄉㄲ㐳㘮㤵〉㘮㜴渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䠉शठठㄭ㘸㈸㜵〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊ㄲ䄉ㄱ渉愯渉⽧䱭ⴉ㜱㤷㘶⸸〰रㄭ㤷㜵㈷〮〰㈉㜲㐷㐮㔹ㄉ㈮㠶渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䄉㈱\u2009\u2009ⴉ㠱ㄱ㜸⸶〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d㉓लㅂऱ⽮ॡ杮洯ौㄲㄴ⸰〰र〱㐸㘲〮〰ㄉ㌲㔰⸹〲षㄱ⸳㤴श⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅂलठठ㤱㐵㈴〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊㌲䌉ㄱ渉愯渉⽧䱭ㄉ㌶㠲㔱〮〰ㄉ㌷㌴㜷㔮〰ㄉ㌴㌶⸱㘰व⸸㠲ऱ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅃलठठ㠱㔳㐹⸰〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d㉓ऴㅄऱ⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㤲㤸ㄴ⸴〰रㄳ㌶㠷⸵〰र㐲㔶㜹㠮㌳㜉㜮㐹渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䐉㈱\u2009\u2009㌉㌳ㄸ㘵〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊㔲䔉ㄱ渉愯渉⽧䱭㜉㐲㐱㈴〮〰㜉㜰㘳〴〮〰㈉㜳〳⸷㘸ऴ⸳㔳व⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठㅅलठठ㤶㔰㌸⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d㍓䌉ष⽮ॡ杮洯ौ㐲㘷㤷㠶〮〰㈉㌴㐶㔷⸹〰र㜵㈰㌲㘮㘳㈉㌮〴渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯渉愯ഉ\u200a䌉सठठ㌲㘹㔱〵〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊ऴ㝄渉愯渉⽧䱭㔉㘷〸㐵〮〰㘉〱㔶㐴〮〰㐉㠷㤶⸷㐱ह⸷㌸ह⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㡄\u2009\u2009㘉㐴〵㐳〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊व㝅渉愯渉⽧䱭㌉㈱〳㜱〮〰㌉ㄱ㤷㈸〮〰㜉㈱⸰㘵व⸰㈲स⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㡅\u2009\u2009㌉ㄱ㤲㜴〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊श㝆渉愯渉⽧䱭ㄉ㈸㔶㈵〮〰ㄉ〷㔸〰㔮〰ㄉ㘶㔹⸰㌰ल⸹㜷ल⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㡆\u2009\u2009ㄉ㤵㐰㤴〮〰\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009\u2009ഉ匊ष㝇渉愯渉⽧䱭㘉〰㐷〮〰㤉〹㘳〮〰㔉ㄵ〰㔮㤸㔉⸵㌶ष⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㡇\u2009\u2009ㄉ㜳㤹⸸〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d㡓䠉ष⽮ॡ杮洯ौㄭ㤸㤲㤳〮〰ⴉ㠱〶〸⸹〰र㔴㌴⸸㠶ल⸲㐴ल⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ⽮ॡ\u0a0dठ㡈\u2009\u2009ⴉ㠱㠲㜶⸹〰रठठठठठठठठठठ\u0a0d\u0a0d片畯⁰潃畬湭䘉牯畭慬丠浡॥潆浲汵ॡ牐捥獩潩८潎慴楴湯\u0a0dऱ慓灭敬℉慓灭敬慎敭ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dल敗汬℉敗汬䑉ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dळ潃据∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㐊唉楮ॴ渢⽧䱭ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dव䙒ॕ圡汥噬污敵ॳ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dश敍湡䙒ॕ癁牥条⡥圡汥噬污敵⥳㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣ㜊匉摴癥匉摴癥ℨ敗汬慖畬獥ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dस䌥ॖ癃ℨ敗汬慖畬獥ऩ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0dह䍂ृ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d〱䴉慥䉮䍃∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊऱ䌥彖䍂ृ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㈱┉䕒∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣㄊळ吥ॅ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㐱䄉瑣癩瑩ॹ渢愯ढ″敤楣慭\u206c汰捡獥三浵牥捩\u0a0d㔱䴉慥䅮瑣∉⽮≡㌉搠捥浩污瀠慬散ॳ畎敭楲ൣഊ䜊潲灵匠浵慭楲獥\u0a0d䕾摮ഠ伊楲楧慮\u206c楆敬慮敭›䑉⁓獡慳⁹整灭慬整损潬敮瀠慬整〠ㄹ㈰‰牴⁹条楡㭮䐠瑡\u2065慌瑳匠癡摥›⼹〱㈯㈰‰㨴㐴㐺‸䵐'`

Comment: Try encoding `"utf_8_sig"`. Taking a few very first "_CJK_" characters from your example, I see a UTF-8 BOM: `'믯⎿䈣佌䭃㵓ㄠല'.encode('utf_16_le').decode('cp1252')` returns `'ï»¿##BLOCKS= 12\r'`…

Comment: UTF-8 is a more identifiable encoding as it follows strict rules. Try it first as `utf-8-sig` (removes BOM if present) and fallback to `utf16` (which requires a BOM), then `utf-16le` (which doesn’t).

Comment: Also, seriously, we didn’t need to see all that file. A couple lines is fine.